# Using forwardRef with HOC in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to make a react HOC, but I am having problems, here's my code:

```
import React, { type FC, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { ButtonBase, ButtonBaseProps } from '@mui/material'

export default function withTouchRipple<PROPS>(OriginalComponent: FC<PROPS>) {
  return forwardRef((props: any, ref) => <ButtonBase {...props} ref={ref} component={OriginalComponent} />)
}
```

- I am using MUI.

It works well. However, I want to remove the `any` type from `props: any`, it should be `PROPS`, so the interface of the props of the given component `OriginalComponent` will be visibie from outside.

but when I do so, typescript complains:

Here's the code after the change and here's the compile error:

```
import React, { type FC, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { ButtonBase, ButtonBaseProps } from '@mui/material'

export default function withTouchRipple<PROPS>(OriginalComponent: FC<PROPS>) {
  return forwardRef((props: PROPS, ref) => <ButtonBase {...props} ref={ref} component={OriginalComponent} />)
}
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { action?: Ref<ButtonBaseActions> | undefined; centerRipple?: boolean | undefined; children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonBaseClasses> | undefined; ... 10 more ...; touchRippleRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'ForwardedRef<unknown>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement> | null | undefined'.
        Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
          Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
            Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAnchorElement | null'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: FC<PROPS>; } & { action?: Ref<ButtonBaseActions> | undefined; centerRipple?: boolean | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 11 more ...; touchRippleRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & DistributiveOmit<...>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'PROPS & { ref: ForwardedRef<unknown>; component: FC<PROPS>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: FC<PROPS>; } & { action?: Ref<ButtonBaseActions> | undefined; centerRipple?: boolean | undefined; ... 12 more ...; touchRippleRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & DistributiveOmit<...>'.
      Type 'PROPS & { ref: ForwardedRef<unknown>; component: FC<PROPS>; }' is not assignable to type 'DistributiveOmit<PropsWithRef<PROPS>, keyof CommonProps | "tabIndex" | "children" | "action" | "centerRipple" | "disabled" | "disableRipple" | "disableTouchRipple" | ... 6 more ... | "touchRippleRef">'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonBaseTypeMap<{}, "button">>>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'ForwardedRef<unknown>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined'.
        Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'.
          Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
            Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement | null'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(805, 46): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { action?: Ref<ButtonBaseActions> | undefined; centerRipple?: boolean | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 11 more ...; touchRippleRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'
index.d.ts(805, 46): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { action?: Ref<ButtonBaseActions> | undefined; centerRipple?: boolean | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 11 more ...; touchRippleRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React.forwardRef` is a generic function and you can pass your generic type as follows:

```
import { type FC, forwardRef } from "react";
import { ButtonBase } from "@mui/material";

export default function withTouchRipple<PROPS>(
  OriginalComponent: FC<PROPS>,
  displayName: string
) {
  const component = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, PROPS>((props, ref) => (
    <ButtonBase {...props} ref={ref} component={OriginalComponent} />
  ));
  component.displayName = displayName;
  return component;
}
```

Comment: How did you know the required type in the first generic type argument was `HTMLButtonElement`?

Comment: If you hover your mouse pointer over the `ButtonBase` `ref` attribute, IntelliSense shows the expected type.